# Execute some functions without submit and then submit

Tags: jquery

I have two inputs the must be validate on submit.
I'm trying this:

```
$("#phase1_form").submit(function(e){
    var result1 = $("#phase1_responsVibleByFirstSignOff").isValid();
    var result2 = $("#phase1_responsibleBySecondSignOff").isValid();
   if ((result1
        && result2
    ))  
    {   
        return true;                                                                                                                                      
    }   
});
```

But the "isValid" function is not so fast and the form is submitted.
I though that maybe I could use the "preventDefault" method, but I have no idea how to "cancel" the effect of this method after the "isValid" function returns some result.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about the speed of the `isValid` function, the submit will definitely wait for the result. The problem is that you only return `true` or `undefined`, but you need to return `false` to stop the form from submitting:

```
$("#phase1_form").submit(function(e){
  var result1 = $("#phase1_responsVibleByFirstSignOff").isValid();
  var result2 = $("#phase1_responsibleBySecondSignOff").isValid();
  return result1 && result2;
});
```